# Provide annotations (similiar to testNG in Java) to group Python Selenium Tests

Tags: python, testing, selenium, ant

I'm refactoring a suite of Selenium tests written in Python. When I did Java a few years back, I used testNG to annotate and group the tests (Smoke Test, Regression, etc). My Ant script allowed the user to run any set of tests, by using the testng directive to select which group to execute.

Is there something similar for Selenium w/Python?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Try [PyUnit](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PyUnit).
It's not that great like Junit but support decent features. Like `setUp` and `tearDown`.